# javascript pivot array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pivot

I need a little help to reorganize this array of objects:

```
[
  {employee: "PLUTO", "MON1": 6},
  {employee: "PLUTO", "TUE2": 6},
  //etc..
  {employee: "DONALD", "MON1":7},
  {employee: "DONALD", "TUE2":7},
  //etc...
]
```

I need to get a result like:

```
[
  {employee: "PLUTO", "MON1":6, "TUE2":6, "etc...."},
  {employee: "DONALD", "MON1":7, "TUE2",7", "etc..."}
]
```

I'm able to get only one object with reduce function to create a new object:

```
var test = myArr.reduce((acc, it) => Object.assign(acc, it), {});
console.log(test); 
[{employee: "DONALD", "MON1":7, "TUE2":7, "etc..."}] <--get only the last employee
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can make use reduce to group the data by name and take `Object.values` in the last:

```js
const arr = [
  {employee: "PLUTO", "MON1": 6},
  {employee: "PLUTO", "TUE2": 6},
  //etc..
  {employee: "DONALD", "MON1":7},
  {employee: "DONALD", "TUE2":7},
  //etc...
];


const result = arr.reduce((a,e)=>(a[e.employee]={...(a[e.employee] || {}), ...e}, a),{});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
 myArr.reduce((acc,it)=>{
   const index = acc.map(i=>i.employee).indexOf(it.employee);
   if(index === -1)
     acc.push(it);
   else
     Object.assign(acc[index],it);
   return acc;
 },[])
```